The username is changed when the login form is submitted
I'm having an issue with Drupal 10. My username is "admin" and my password is "admin123," but it shows "Unrecognized username or password. Forgot your password?" When I submit the login form, the username changes to "~{rvq".



Do you have any idea why the username and password are from "admin" and "admin123" to "~{rvq" and "Mppk.-<&/"?
This is the code I am using.
if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'form_build_id_validation';
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="maf-lgn-heading mb-4">Login to Gateway</div>';
  $form['name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'maf-nav-input-txt input-logo email mb-4';
  $form['pass']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'maf-nav-input-txt input-logo pwd mb-1'; 
  $form['name']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
  $form['pass']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
  $form['name']['#placeholder'] = 'Email';
  $form['pass']['#placeholder'] = 'Password';
  $form['pass']['#suffix'] = '<div class="maf-lgn-fgt-password text-left text-sm-left text-md-right text-lg-right mb-5"><a href="/user/password" class="maf-login-fgt-pwd text-white">Forgot password?</a></div>'; 
  $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center mb-2 mb-sm-2 mb-md-2 mb-lg-0 mb-xl-0">
              <div class="d-inline-block maf-lgn-inline-account"></div></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-6 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-sm-end justify-content-md-end">';
  $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';
       
  unset($form['name']['#description']); 
  unset($form['pass']['#description']);
}

This is the code in the template file.
<div class="maf-login-wrap min-100 vh-100 position-relative clear-vh-height-at-xs">
  <div class="maf-login-main">
    <div class="maf-login-header space-120-lr d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex align-items-center my-3 my-sm-3 my-md-0 my-lg-0 my-xl-0 clear-vh-height-at-xs">
            <div class="app-logo">
              <img src="/{{ active_theme_path() }}/images/app-logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start justify-content-sm-start justify-content-md-end justify-content-lg-end justify-content-xl-end mb-3 mb-sm-3 mb-md-0 mb-lg-0 mb-xl-0">
            <!-- <a href="/user/register" class="login-sign-up-no-br">Sign Up</a -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maf-login-form min-100 vh-100 space-120-lr position-relative">
      <div class="maf-login-content w-100">
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7 d-flex flex-column align-items center justify-content-center min-100 vh-100 clear-vh-height-at-xs">
              <div class="maf-lgn-input-form d-flex flex-column align-items center justify-content-center p-3 p-sm-3 p-md-3 p-lg-0 p-xl-0">
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- Repeat section for all the login forms // row common-->
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                </div>
                <!-- Login form center row for the first section -->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                  <!--Login Form -->
                  {{ page.content }}
                </div>
              </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="maf-lgn-footer-credits position-absolute">Gateway 2020</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 


Is this your browser auto-filling values?

Or some javascript functionality messing about with the values. See what .js files are loaded on the page and investigate. Has to be something frontend as the values are changes before they reach the server
